# Connection failed upon using ElasticSearch or OpenSearch python client but able to establish connection through curl. How to resolve?

Tags: python, rest, elasticsearch, opensearch

Trying to connect to ES cluster using Python client. When I check connection through curl I am able to connect:
[image: Curl]

But when I try using ElasticSearch package and followed the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/connecting.html) I get Connection failed upon ping:

```
headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer "+auth_token}
es = Elasticsearch(
    'https://cluster.xyz.com:443',
    bearer_auth=auth_token,
    request_timeout=10,
    verify_certs=False
)
if not es.ping():
    raise ValueError("Connection failed")
```

> ### Error:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) es = Elasticsearch(
> 'https:/cluster.xyz.com:443',
> bearer_auth=auth_token,
> request_timeout=10,
> verify_certs=False
> )
> if not es.ping():
> --->     raise ValueError("Connection failed")
>
> ValueError: Connection failed

I used the same exact token in variable `auth_token` upon curl so I am sure about the token being correct. Why am I not able to connect in this case? Same thing happen when I try using OpenSearch.

Error message:
[image: Error]

Comment: And you're using the 7.9.1 elasticsearch python client library as well?

Comment: 7.9.1 upon checking our clean staging cluster. As for the ES python library version it's 8.10.1, the latest. I even tried to downgrade the python library to elsaticsearch7 (7.10) but it's the same result when I to ping.

Comment: You should definitely not use a 8.10 client with a 7.9 cluster, so stick with the 7.10 one and let's figure it out

Comment: For one the URL is missing a forward slash after the scheme: `https:/cluster.xyz.com:443` should be `https://cluster.xyz.com:443`

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong, it is missing a forward slash after the scheme. Also you can remove the `headers` variable since you specify `bearer_auth` and hence you are not using the headers.

This code should work:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    'https://cluster.xyz.com:443',           <--- fix this
    bearer_auth=auth_token,
    request_timeout=10,
    verify_certs=False
)
if not es.ping():
    raise ValueError("Connection failed")
```

Comment: My mistake on the url part as I had to replace it in this post but yes I have the forward slash and it gives me >>TransportError: TransportError(302, '{"Message":"Authorization >>has been denied for this request."}')
I

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve connection issue using a different approach:

```
es = Elasticsearch(es_url, headers=headers[environment], verify_certs=False)
```

This seems to work but when using `bearer_auth`, I am encountering the error.